# Joining table to collection doesn't work but getData shows joined fields

Tags: join, join-table

## The problem

I have joined the category product list collection (`getLoadedProductCollection` from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`) with a custom table. Because this collection is loaded from `_beforeToHtml` we have to update it via observer event:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <promotion_list_collection>
                    <class>promotion/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogBlockProductListCollection</method>
                </promotion_list_collection>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
```

I am using this as my join:

```
public function catalogBlockProductListCollection($observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');

    $collection->joinTable(
        array('promotion'=>'custom_promotion'),
        'sku=sku',
        array('up_coupon_upc'=>'up_coupon_upc')
        );

}
```

But it turns out that that after it is loaded the column `up_coupon_upc` is not added to the collection. It is, however, available if you `$collection->getData()` to dump the contents of the loaded collection.

## Things I've tried

I assumed that perhaps it wasn't actually adding to the MCMP model in the collection, so I have tried adding the attribute to the select:

```
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('up_coupon_upc');
```

Doesn't work. I tried using various aliases. I tried using `$collection->getSelect()->join()` instead with the same result.

I also have tried to define other columns - none of which show up either. Doing `array('*')` adds all columns to my SQL query, but none of the attributes actually show up, though 
the SQL output from `$collection->getSelect()` outputs exactly the correct query.

## Guesses

I'm guessing that the modification of the collection is actually taking place either only within the scope of the Observer, or the product collection is somehow being `load`-ed prior to my observer being called.

Or, perhaps I'm just having a monumental fail and I've missed something obvious .

Comment: What does the dispatchEvent pass in your magento version in 1.8 it only passes the select instead of the collection 

Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before', array('select' => $select))

Comment: My apologies - wrong event. Updated.

Comment: And it passes the collection -         Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
            'collection' => $this->_getProductCollection()
        ));

Comment: What does (string)$this->_getProductCollection()->getSelect(); output afterwards?

Comment: See the SQL output here: https://gist.github.com/philwinkle/8840d68d76fcebc2fd22

Comment: In my case the product collection is already loaded before it hits that event. Can you check $this->_getProductCollection()->isLoaded()?

Comment: Correct, it is loaded. I mentioned that - trying to find an earlier event or find the culprit of the load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said collection could already be loaded (and therefor won't reload). You can check this via  `$this->_getProductCollection()->isLoaded()`

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to Martjin for his help.

In my case the collection was already explicitly loaded by `Mage_Review`. In order to affect my collection change ahead of Mage_Review I needed to make Mage_Review depend on my module.

Thankfully this is easy to do with my module's `app/modules/` registration XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <PJ_Promotion>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </PJ_Promotion>
        <Mage_Review>
            <depends>
                <PJ_Promotion/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_Review>
    </modules>
</config>
```

## Additional information

I was able to skirt this without needing to join after all. Taking some inspiration from `Mage_Review` I instead opted to add the table collection to the product collection by iterating. This is how Mage Review does it:

**Event Listener:**

```
public function catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    if ($productCollection instanceof Varien_Data_Collection) {
        $productCollection->load();
        Mage::getModel('review/review')->appendSummary($productCollection);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**Model append method:**

```
/**
 * Append review summary to product collection
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection $collection
 * @return Mage_Review_Model_Review
 */
public function appendSummary($collection)
{
    $entityIds = array();
    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $_itemId => $_item) {
        $entityIds[] = $_item->getEntityId();
    }

    if (sizeof($entityIds) == 0) {
        return $this;
    }

    $summaryData = Mage::getResourceModel('review/review_summary_collection')
        ->addEntityFilter($entityIds)
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load();

    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $_item ) {
        foreach ($summaryData as $_summary) {
            if ($_summary->getEntityPkValue() == $_item->getEntityId()) {
                $_item->setRatingSummary($_summary);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```